# Finding the currently focussed windows element using JNA

Tags: java, jna

I'm trying to access the current windows element in focus using JNA. `PresentationCore.dll` has `Keyboard.FocusedElement` function that seems to be what I need. How do I call this function?

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible Because FocusedElement is not exported as a shared library function, try to opeen that DLL using [this tool](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e1a26812-def5-4dc5-b667-88e8b205df56/add-a-reference-to-presentationcoredll-in-a-windows-forms-application?forum=vbide)